# How do i bake a material onto an image texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, texture-painting

Just did some texture painting and wasn't happy how the colours turned out so I added a colour ramp in the node editor, is there any way to bake the new colours made by the colour ramp onto the image texture?[image]

Comment: Add a new image node disconnected and add a new image there of sufficient size and bake it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I added a new image node with a large generated image texture, disconnected from the node chain. I added an Emission node to feed my adjusted painted texture into instead of the diffuse shader so that I could bake the Emit output and get the same color info without any shading added.
[image]